# Can I read Stack Overflow in Immersive (reading mode) in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: support, microsoft-edge

While navigating on Microsoft Edge, on some webpages I can enter Immersive Reading mode by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> or by clicking the icon on the address bar. Is it possible (maybe using a "wrapper web) to read Stack Overflow responses on this mode?

Answer (score 1):

From [this doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/enter-reading-view-with-immersive-reader-in-microsoft-edge-72ac6331-2795-42eb-b3e8-c03503231f32), we can know that if you don't see Immersive Reader in the address bar, it might be that the web page isn't an article, or some content is missing when opened in reading view.

You can use the following ways to enter Immersive Reader:

- Add the prefix **read:** to the URL in the address bar and press Enter. But in my test, using this way to enter Immersive Reader on stackoverflow will only show the question part.

  [image]
- Select the text that you want to read, right-click, and from the context menu, select **Open in Immersive Reader**.

  [image]